# Bit Grouping in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting, conversion

I'm currently doing some Discrete Math homework involving converting between base 10, 2, 8, and 16. The professor showed us the method of converting from base 10 to binary first, then using bit grouping to convert to bases 8 and 16. Example:

```
32 base 10 = 100000 base 2
             100 000
             4   0
           = 40 base 8
```

Now I would like to be able to demonstrate something similar in LaTeX. However, I can't seem to get the formatting right. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit

So here's what I tried

```
\begin{align*}
\texttt{100000101010} \\
\texttt{1001 0001 1011} \\
\texttt{   9    1    B} \\
2331_{10} = \mathtt{91B_{16}}
\end{align*}
```

Basically I just want the numbers in the third \texttt to line up with the last digit of the grouping in the line above it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you show an example of what you've tried (in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))? Should the output be as the code block you show above?

Comment: Sure, sorry. I think my edit should count as an MWE? If it doesn't let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that use of  verbatim environment will the simple solution:

```
\begin{verbatim}
        100000101010
        1001 0001 1011
           9    1    B
\end{verbatim}
\[            
2331_{10} = \mathtt{91B_{16}}
\]
```

Results of above code is as code between `begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` looks now and below it given equation.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Here are another option with a regular `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  32 \text{ base } 10 &= 100000 \text{ base } 2 \\
             &\phantom{{}={}}  100\,000 \\
             &\phantom{{}={}}  4\phantom{00\,}0 \\
             &= 40 \text{ base } 8 \\
  32_{10} &= 100000_2 \\
          &\phantom{{}={}}  100\,000 \\
          &\phantom{{}={}}  4\phantom{00\,}0 \\
          &= 40_8
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one looks really professional. Unfortunately, I can't be bothered to type this out for each of my problems, so I'll be using the \verbatim solution. However, for anything more professional I'll definitely use this :)

Answer (score 1):

## array

You could use an `array` together with the `array` package to set formatting to the columns.  To get the typewriter font in math mode you unfortunately have to use the deprecated `\tt` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{>{\tt}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}*{3}{@{}>{\tt}r}}
              & & 1000 & 0010 & 1010 \\
              & & 1001 & 0001 & 1011 \\
              & &    9 &    1 &    B \\
    2331_{10} &=& 91B_{16}           \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## tabular

As @egreg suggested in the comments, you can also typeset the whole thing in text mode using a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
  \ttfamily
  \begin{tabular}{r@{\ }c@{\ }*{3}{r@{}}}
    & & 1000 & 0010 & 1010 \\
    & & 1001 & 0001 & 1011 \\
    & &    9 &    1 &    B \\
    2331\textsubscript{10} &=& 91B\textsubscript{16} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## active characters

For a super easy syntax you could make `_` and the newline active.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newenvironment{bitalign}
  {\begin{center}\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    \ttfamily \parindent=0pt \obeyspaces \obeylines
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\par\leavevmode}
    \catcode`_=13 \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\textsubscript}}
  {\end{varwidth}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{bitalign}
         100000101010
         100100011011
            9   1   B
2331_{10} = 91B_{16}
\end{bitalign}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Ever heard about `\ttfamily`? `;-)` Why should you use math mode throughout when you just need it for a couple of subscripts?

Comment: ...also, the base 10 is not in `\ttfamily`.